# Ruby titleize is removing Hyphen, how to override?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
 q = ["2002-h2","2002-h1", "2000-h1", "2005-h2", "2000-h2", "2005-h1"]

 q.sort_by { |a| a }.collect{|u| u}

 => ["2000-h1", "2000-h2", "2002-h1", "2002-h2", "2005-h1", "2005-h2"]
```

when i'm using titleize its removing Hyphen symols

```
 q.sort_by { |a| a }.collect{|u| u.titleize}

 => ["2000 H1", "2000 H2", "2002 H1", "2002 H2", "2005 H1", "2005 H2"]
```

i want like this type

```
 => ["2000-H1", "2000-H2", "2002-H1", "2002-H2", "2005-H1", "2005-H2"]
```

i want sort q values

How to fix this one?

Comment: Why are you using titleize rather than upcase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just 1 letter? Then just `upcase`?

```
[1] pry(main)> "2000-h1".upcase
=> "2000-H1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this even shorter, because `.sort_by { |a| a }` returns the same than just `.sort` and `.collect { |a| a.upcase }` returns the same than `.map(&:upcase)`

```
q = ["2002-h2","2002-h1", "2000-h1", "2005-h2", "2000-h2", "2005-h1"]

q.sort.map(&:upcase)

#=> ["2000-H1", "2000-H2", "2002-H1", "2002-H2", "2005-H1", "2005-H2"]
```